# mixed linear models comparison

Tags: r, mixed-model, linear-model, model-comparison

When I get 2 mixed linear Models for a comparison between them

For example,
(B, C, D are factors)

Mdoel 1 <- lmer(A ~ B * C * D + (1|individual), data = Data_1) in script
Outcome in console:
A ~ B * C * D + (1 | individual)

Model 2 <- update(Model 1, . ~ . - B : C : D) in script
Outcome in console :
A ~ B + C + D + (1 | individual) + B:C + B:D + C:D

1. Also, B,C,D are for fixed effects and (1|individual) is for a random effect

What is the difference between A ~ B + C + D + (1|individual) and A ~ B*C*D + (1|individual)?

2. By Model 2 what do mean ". ~ ." and "- B : C : D" both in Script?

2-2. A ~ B + C + D + (1 | individual) + B:C + B:D + C:D
What does mean " B:C + B:D + C:D "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between A ~ B + C + D + (1|individual) and A ~ BCD + (1|individual)?

I think you mean `B * C * D`, not `BCD`. `BCD` would represent a variable called `BCD`, wheras `B * C * D` means "fit fixed effects for `B`, `C` and `D`, and all the interactions between them" (that is, the three 2-way interactions plus the 3 way interaction). So the difference betwwen `A ~ B + C + D`  and `A ~ B * C * D` is that in the former we fit fixed effects for the each of the variables while in the latter we also fit all the interactions.

> By Model2 what do mean ". ~ ." and "- B : C : D" both in Script?

You are telling the software to update model 1 by removing  the 3-way interaction `B:C:D`(because you used the minus symbol `-`), so that model 2 contains only the 2-way interactions (and the main effects)

> What does mean "B:C + B:D + C:D"?

`B:C + B:D + C:D` tells the software to fit the three 2-way interactions between the variables. Note that

```
~ B * C * D
```

is exactly the same as:

```
~ B + C + D + B:C + B:D + C:D
```

Comment: Super super thank you I did understand totally :) I have one more question so I did AIC and BIC for model comparison model 1 has more information than model 2 cuz model 2 has no information about 3-way interaction but the outcome of AIC and BIC tells the model 2 is better is it possible?

Comment: You're welcome :) Yes that is possible !